# How to get all HTTP requests from a page

Tags: python, http

How can I capture all the HTTP requests from a page. For example, http://google.com? I tried Python using `urllib`, but so far I found it only returns the final content of the page.

I would like also a list of all the requests.

Comment: What do you mean all the requests? The redirects? The links on the page?

Comment: @Artyer I think OP refers to all the secondary requests made by the browser for all the resources on google.com

Comment: Yes that's the actual question sorry :)

Comment: Well, you would need to actually use a browser for that (not necessarly literally, it might be some browser engine) since it understands JavaScript and knows when and what calls to do. This is highly nontrivial task though.

Comment: I see :). Do you have any example ?

Comment: I've managed to do this by using the selenium webdriver and a proxy within python ! Thanks all for the answers.